# html to pdf issue - problem with css transform scale and page-break

Tags: html, css, dompdf

I'm writing a code to render PDF from HTML PDF. I'm using Dompdf to make a record of table. And it is working for me. Here is the picture of my table: [Table 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3TlnC.jpg)

There is a trouble with my code. I can't display the whole data from table. I have already using CSS transform and page-break. Here is my code:

```
    <html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">


            .content {
                transform: scale(.56);
                margin-left:-30px;
                position:absolute;


            }

            table {
                border-collapse: collapse;
                border-spacing: 0;
                margin-bottom: 0;
                page-break-inside:auto;




            }

            table tr:nth-child(2n-1) td {
                background-color: #ffffff;
                border:1px solid black;
                page-break-inside:auto;


            }
            table th {
                padding: 0px;
                white-space: normal;        
                font-weight: normal;
                border:1px solid black;
                page-break-inside:auto;
            }
            table td {
                padding: 0px;
                white-space: normal;
                text-align: center;
                border:1px solid black;
                page-break-inside:auto;
            }

            @media print {
                    body {
                        margin-top: 100cm;
                        page-break-after: always;
                        display: inline;
                    }


        </style>

    </head>

    <body>

        <div class="content">
            <table>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th  rowspan="2" style="width: 20px">#</th>  
                        <th colspan="8" style="text-align: center;width: 500px">Tanggal - Jam</th>
                        <th rowspan="2" style="text-align: center;width: 50px">No PO</th>
                        <th rowspan="2" style="text-align: center;width: 50px">No DO</th>
                        <th rowspan="2" style="text-align: center;width: 150px">No BM</th>
                        <th rowspan="2" style="text-align: center;width: 150px">No SJ</th>
                        <th rowspan="2" style="text-align: center;width: 50px">No Unit</th>
                        <th rowspan="2" style="text-align: center;width: 50px">No Polisi</th>                        
                        <th rowspan="2" style="text-align: center;width: 80px">Nama Konsumen</th>
                        <th rowspan="2" style="text-align: center;width: 80px">Jenis Kendaraan</th>
                        <th rowspan="2" style="text-align: center;width: 80px">Nama Supir</th>
                        <th rowspan="2" style="text-align: center;width: 80px">Jenis Transaksi</th>
                        <th rowspan="2" style="text-align: center;width: 80px">Nama Material</th>
                        <th colspan="2" style="text-align: center;width: 80px">Jumlah</th>
                        <th rowspan="2" style="text-align: center;width: 60px">Material (Rp.)</th>
                        <th rowspan="2" style="text-align: center;width: 60px">CSR (Rp.)</th>
                        <th rowspan="2" style="text-align: center;width: 60px">ATP (Rp.)</th>
                        <th rowspan="2" style="text-align: center;width: 60px">Total (Rp.)</th>
                        <th rowspan="2" style="text-align: center;width: 50px">Proyek</th>
                        <th rowspan="2" style="text-align: center;width: 100px">Tujuan</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th colspan="2" style="text-align: center"> Masuk</th>
                        <th colspan="2" style="text-align: center"> Produksi</th>
                        <th colspan="2" style="text-align: center"> Timbang</th>
                        <th colspan="2" style="text-align: center"> Keluar</th>
                        <th style="text-align: center"> K </th>
                        <th style="text-align: center"> T </th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <?php
                    $no = 0;
                    foreach ($list_data as $data) {
                        $no++;
                        $tonasesatuan = $data['netto'] / 1000;
                        ?>
                        <tr>
                            <td><?php echo $no; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo date_dmy($data['tanggal']); ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo date_time($data['tanggal']); ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo date_dmy($data['tanggal_produksi']); ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo date_time($data['tanggal_produksi']); ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo date_dmy($data['tanggal_out']); ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo date_time($data['tanggal_out']); ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo date_dmy($data['tanggal_timbang']); ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo date_time($data['tanggal_timbang']); ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $data['no_po']; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $data['no_do']; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $data['no_bm']; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $data['no_sj']; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo getLabelIndex($data['nopol'], 'no_unit'); ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $data['nopol']; ?></td>
                            <td style="text-align: center"><?php echo $data['nama_konsumen']; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $jeniskendaraan = strtoupper($data['jenis_kendaraan']); ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $data['supir']; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $data['jenis_transaksi']; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $data['nama_material']; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $kubikasi = number_format($data['hasil'], 2, '.', ','); ?> m<sup>3</sup></td>
                            <td><?php echo $netto = number_format($tonasesatuan, 2, '.', ','); ?> Ton</td>
                            <td style="text-align: right"><?php echo number_format($data['total_material']); ?></td>
                            <td style="text-align: right"><?php echo number_format($data['csr']); ?></td>
                            <td style="text-align: right"><?php echo number_format($data['atp']); ?></td>
                            <td style="text-align: right"><?php echo number_format($data['total_bayar']); ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo getLabelNamaProyek($data['proyek'], 'nama_proyek'); ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $data['tujuan']; ?></td>
                        </tr>
                        <?php
                        $tronton += $jeniskendaraan == 'TRONTON';
                        $colt += $jeniskendaraan == 'COLT DIESEL';
                        $engkel += $jeniskendaraan == 'ENGKEL';
                        $pick += $jeniskendaraan == 'PICK UP';
                        $totkubikasi += $kubikasi;
                        $totnetto += $tonasesatuan;
                        $no;
                        $kubik = $totkubikasi / $no;
                        $ton = $totnetto / $no;
                    }
                    ?>
                </tbody>
                <tfoot>

                </tfoot>
            </table>
            <br>
            <br>
            <table>
                 <tfoot>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="text-align: center; color: red;"> #</td>
                        <td colspan="8" style="text-align: center; color: red;"> TOTAL ARMADA</td>
                        <td colspan="4" style="text-align: center; color: red;"><?php echo round($tronton, 2); ?> TRONTON</td>
                        <td colspan="4" style="text-align: center; color: red;"><?php echo round($colt, 2); ?> COLT DIESEL</td>
                        <td colspan="4" style="text-align: center; color: red;"><?php echo round($engkel, 2); ?> ENGKEL</td>
                        <td colspan="4" style="text-align: center; color: red;"><?php echo round($pick, 2); ?> PICK UP</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="text-align: center; color: red;"> #</td>
                        <td colspan="8" style="text-align: center; color: red;"> TOTAL KUBIKASI</td>
                        <td colspan="4" style="text-align: center; color: red;"><?php echo number_format($totkubikasi, 2, '.', ','); ?> m<sup>3</sup></td>
                        <td colspan="4" style="text-align: center; color: red;"> TOTAL TONASE</td>
                        <td colspan="8" style="text-align: center; color: red;"><?php echo number_format($totnetto, 2, '.', ','); ?> Ton</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="text-align: center; color: red;"> #</td>
                        <td colspan="8" style="text-align: center; color: red;">RATA - RATA KUBIKASI</td>
                        <td colspan="4" style="text-align: center; color: red;"><?php echo number_format($kubik, 2, '.', ','); ?> m<sup>3</sup></td>
                        <td colspan="4" style="text-align: center; color: red;">RATA - RATA TONASE</td>
                        <td colspan="8" style="text-align: center; color: red;"><?php echo number_format($ton, 2, '.', ','); ?> Ton</td>
                    </tr>
                </tfoot>
            </table>
        </div>
    </body>
    </div>
</head>
</html>
```

I have to add another page on it, but it seems hard for me after days of trial and error. Please, could anybody help me?

Answer (score 0):

Try after removing absolute from the div with content class.

Comment: Yes, i have it. and it work. Page is split into several page, but it left a huge space bellow the table. I need to make the table more fit with page's size. Any suggestion?

Comment: In my view it won't be possible to reduce the gap below the table as the height of the table depends on the number of the table rows it has. :(

Comment: Ok. Thank you for your advice. So, is it possible by making a change in font size?

Comment: yes it can reduce the height of the row and overall table too, but not sure whole content will fit inside the page or not. If the content is more than the height of the page it will again result in the same issue.